# Disable autocomplete forms in browser

Tags: drupal, autocomplete

I've got Drupal site, and I try to disable the autocomplete which was made by browser (like Firefox). I put Autocomplete="false" in form/input but nothing happens I always got the autocomplete.

Here's my code

```
<form id="tools-form" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" action="/" autocomplete="false">
<div>
<div class="form-item form-type-select form-item-field-specialites">
<input type="hidden" value="form-SRCZMjW2TL0BmIMj1iFynwQk4_QmrVgFr8zzTSIh_a8" name="form_build_id">
<input type="hidden" value="tools_form" name="form_id">
<div class="form-item form-type-radios form-item-field-pays">
<div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-field-code-postal" role="application">
<label for="edit-field-code-postal">
<input id="edit-field-code-postal" class="form-text required form-autocomplete" type="text" maxlength="128" size="60" value="" name="field_code_postal" autocomplete="OFF" aria-autocomplete="list">
```

---

Here my code

```
<form id="tools-form" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" action="/" autocomplete="false">
<div>
<div class="form-item form-type-select form-item-field-specialites">
<input type="hidden" value="form-SRCZMjW2TL0BmIMj1iFynwQk4_QmrVgFr8zzTSIh_a8" name="form_build_id">
<input type="hidden" value="tools_form" name="form_id">
<div class="form-item form-type-radios form-item-field-pays">
<div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-field-code-postal" role="application">
<label for="edit-field-code-postal">
<input id="edit-field-code-postal" class="form-text required form-autocomplete" type="text" maxlength="128" size="60" value="" name="field_code_postal" autocomplete="OFF" aria-autocomplete="list">
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you post an example?

Also try the following:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete"off" />
```

[Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion)  recommends using `"off"` not `"false"`.

Comment: Of course I try the two way, false and off nothing happen more.....
And I have autocomplete=off (or false) on <form > and on <input>.....

Answer (score 0):

In firefox you can use AutoComplete ="off"

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TurningOffAutoCompleteForTextBoxesInIEAndFireFox.aspx